# Combine unique answers as "other" in survey evaluation in Excel pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, survey

I have the following table:

```
Do you like apples?

yes
no
no
yes
yes
I do, but not the green ones
I do, but only as pie
```

Now I'd like to create the following chart:

```
Yes   ===   
No    ==   
Other ==
```

How can I unify these "other" values as a filter with MS Excel 2010 Pivot tables?

I know how to create a Top 10, but then the "other" values are just extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column B and write in B2 the following:
`=IF(A2="Yes","Yes",IF(A2="No","No","Other"))`
A2 is your normal answers
You will get:
Yes for Yes
No for No
Other for every answer different from Yes or No
And you can do what ever you need with it

Comment: This is certainly the best concept. You can get fancier with lookup tables if there are a lot of standard answers and return "Other" only when one isn't found in some other list. You *can* group things in a pivot table but it's a pain and messes up when new things are added.

Comment: seams like a missing feature than, thanks, ill try it your way